# Driver path is None but file location can be found

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-python

I have a web scraper that uses Undetected Chromedriver & WebDriverManager to download & automate a Chromium webdriver.

On Windows I initialize the Undetcted Chromedriver instance by passing the `executable_path` to the output of `ChromeDriverManager().install()`. This works fine.

Now I am trying to Dockerize my application, however I am getting:

> Error: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

when trying to initialize my object as lined out below. I'm not getting any other context to where the error is being raised from.

Driver initialisation

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
path = ChromeDriverManager(os_type="linux64").install()
driver = uc.Chrome(
    options=options, executable_path=path, force=True
)
```

I've also tried:

1. Check if the file at the path **ChromeDriverManager.install()** returns exists using `os.path.isfile()` which returned True
2. Pass a relative path to `executable_path`.

Comment: It could be that `executable_path` is deprecated in new versions. Use `webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path), options=options)` and add this import `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service`.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply @soundwave but this raises the same exception.

Comment: Can you provide a backtrace?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii the exception isn't giving one and I can't get it from `exception.__traceback__` object either.

Comment: did you try using `import traceback` `traceback.print_exc` inside a catch statement?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii I've tried `traceback.print_exc()` inside the catch statement, and I've tried to raise the exception using the `_with_traceback(exception.__traceback__)` and I don't get an actual stack trace, only the error message.

Comment: Hmm well that's weird. Meybe its inside some thread, multiprocess or subprocess. or the exception is only printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite know where it went wrong on my first Docker container but here's how I fixed it:

It seems like the ChromeDriver wasn't being downloaded properly. I'm guessing something to do with `$_PATH` variables.

I installed the Chromedriver through docker by adding this to the Dockerfile

```
RUN wget -q "https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb"
RUN apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

RUN wget -q "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip" -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/ \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Which works great